# LOWERING 60VAC TO 24-30VAC?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

- am trying to lower 60vac, which is the voltage delivered to a fan motor, down to 24vac to run a motorized damper at 0.25 amps.
- have read about the voltage divider but i have not been able to figure out exactly how to go about doing this.
- a transformer would be the simplest for me but i am not sure if i can find something with the ratio needed, 2.5:1.
- fan is automatically controlled by a humidity module, so when the fan starts up , the fan voltage should open the motorized damper.

Comment: Please edit your post to use proper capitalization. A voltage divider will not be appropriate unless you take the (complex) impedance of your source and load into account.

Comment: If in the US, why can't you just use a 120VAC:48VAC transformer? (I didn't know anyone was still using the [Model 32 Teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex#/media/File:Telex_machine_ASR-32.jpg)! -- Ah, upgraded now to a Model 33, I see.)

Comment: 24Vac transformers are common to doorbells and furnaces and are cheap as dirt for 6VA or more

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that the damper is something like this:

[image]

This uses a 120V to 24V transformer to run the damper motor, which runs continuously when activated.

You humidity sensor/fan will also include a transformer, in this case 120V to 60V. The humidity sensor will turn on/off the 120V to the transformer to activate the fan.

You have been quite creative in suggesting driving the damper from the 60V side of the fan configuration, but you don't need to do this.

Tap into to 120V switched side of the humidity sensor transformer, and attach a 120V to 24V transformer to drive the damper. In all probability you can do this either at the output terminals of the humidity sensor or the input terminals to the fan transformer (if it's closer to the damper).

There are plenty of control transformers available such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HPJT7C0) which should adequately power the damper.

Comment: Yes, the transformer and damper you mentioned is exactly what I started with.  Everything you said makes perfect sense.  I tried to get Panasonic tech line to help me with identifying some things on the circuit board but I was unsuccessful.  My lack of knowledge with circuit boards limits my ability to make this work.  I am going to try and get someone locally to assist with the circuit board.  I work for an electric utility and I understand transformers, regulators & such but on a much bigger scale.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRv53C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: it may need a smaller capacitor, depending on the power factor of the damper.

Comment: Thank you for your help.